# Proved that a language is regular

Tags: regular-language

Ι need to prove that this language is regular **L = {ab^j c^j | j ≥ 0} ∪ {a^i b^ j c^k | i, j, k ≥ 0 and i /= 1}**. I have proved that the first track is not regular with Pumping lemma and the second from the link that I post below:  [is regular language L ={a^i b^j c^k | i /= 1}](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2218204/is-regular-language-l-ai-bj-ck-i-1). I have come to a dead-end, I cannot understand the result that the connection of a regular and non-regular gives because can be regular or non - regular. Is it possible to tell me some other approach?

Comment: Denote by $L_1$ the first and $L_2$ the second. Observe that $L_1\cap L_2=\emptyset$. If $L$ were regular, $L\setminus L_2=L_1$ would be regular too. Are you sure you want to prove that $L$ is regular?

Comment: yes ,I believe that is non -regular but i need to prove!!

Comment: If you proved that $L_1$ is non-regular, you're done since $L\setminus L_2=L_1$.